# Excel 2003 XML to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, excel, ssis

I'm writing an SSIS package to import the contents of several Excel files into a SQL Server database for my client. These files will be provided regularly and the system should be completely automated without user involvement.

The Excel files are provided by my client's business partners, so I don't have a lot of control over them.

One of the files seems to be in the Excel 2003 SpreadsheetML XML format. Note that this is different from Open XML. It seems from my research that SSIS cannot read this format. It can and does read "normal" Excel 2003 files just fine.

Does anyone know of a way (in code) to convert this file into either non-XML Excel 2003 or Excel 2007 so I can import it? It needs to be automated, so opening the file using Excel and "save as" another type is off the table.

Comment: You will always need user involvement because people will always be entering unexpected rubbish (on numeric values, formulas, macros, linked data etc.). You can automate Excel Save As functionality in VBA, or .Net (including a script task), but you need to understand your automated process will fail frequently because people put rubbish into Excel.

Comment: Nick, these excel files are machine generated. People should not be entering any unexpected rubbish - people won't be editing them at all, and if they do, the process SHOULD fail.

Comment: OK thats fine, but usually Excel is not the ideal choice for transferring data, for example it automatically truncates leading 0's and various other things. Anyway what you need to do is record a macro in Excel of you saving the file as Excel. Then you convert this macro to .Net code and run it in a SSIS script task. I believe you would need to have Excel installed on your SSIS server but this is only to provide the correct libraries

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126793/automate-process-by-running-excel-vba-macro-in-ssis, although there are many articles saying that you should not be automating Excel on the server side. If possible consider a more suitable data transfer format such as a tab delimited file.