# Make fields dependent on each other when sorting and filtering

Tags: excel, ssis

I created an SSIS package to export an SQL table to Excel. There are nine columns in the export file.

How do I make those fields dependent on each other (or check if they are)?

For example, if a client wants to filter through the year column the other columns change as well, each row of data is connected/related.

If I do format this would I have to do it every time I do an export to Excel, or would it be saved on the template?

```
'Part' 'Year' 'Type' 'Plant' 'Country' 'Source' 'Doctype' 'Company' 'Status'                                                                         
 exd1   2015   rear   001M    mexico    DID      ez-01     ford      active
 pod1   2014   head   001E    Bosnia    DID      ez-02     gm        on-going
 sas1   2015   side   001S    U.S       PID      ez-03     gm        inactive
```

Like the above for example so if I filter for the year for 2015 only then only the first and last row should show up.

Comment: It might help if you include some sample input and an example of the output you are expecting

Comment: @MiguelH I added one in the question thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could script something that runs a macro against the exported excel to add your filters. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126793/automate-process-by-running-excel-vba-macro-in-ssis

Comment: The SSIS answer is to sort the data before writing to Excel. After that, if they want data sorted differently, then you show them how the sort buttons work in Excel

Comment: @MiguelH thank you! I will follow those steps

Comment: and thank you as well @billinkc as well I will sort it out beforehand

Answer (score 0):

> if a client wants to filter through the year column the other columns
>   change as well, each row of data is connected/related.

If this action is post-export-to-Excel where the client interacts with the Excel doc loaded with data, then this can be accommodated by using Excel's Filter by Form functionality.

Otherwise, if you wish to allow the export to choose a year, then hit a 'go' button and then the Excel doc loads with only that year's data, then it's Excel VBA code with a stored procedure behind the scenes.  Check out my article [Microsoft Excel & SQL Server:  Self service BI to give users the data they want](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/13675/Microsoft-Excel-SQL-Server-Self-service-BI-to-give-users-the-data-they-want.html) on how to pull that off.

Another option is to use Power View and create slicers for the years.