# Can a Macro (Excel) be processed by ssis?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ssis

I want to Import an Excel sheet to SQL-Server and I am struggling with the Import. So I have to Change some cells in the Excel sheet before it is possible to Import the sheet. 
the Import should be processed fully automated so I Need a solution which is automatically processed by Excel before SSIS is loading the file.

So is it possible to write a Makro which will be automatically conducted when the loading process is starting?
Or is it possible to excecute an Excel Makro from a SSIS package?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and Excel 2013

Comment: Have a look at that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126793/automate-process-by-running-excel-vba-macro-in-ssis) . Also, please, do try to search for previous answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can create a script task in SSIS and then call macro from VBA code as follows:

oXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXLS.Visible = False

oWbks = oXLS.Workbooks

oFileWbk = oWbks.Open(Dts.Variables("filePath").Value.ToString())

oXLS.Run("MyMacro")